# I can't understand what is wrong with the destructors?

Tags: c++, constructor, virtual-destructor

I have a class called polygon which is my base class in which I have area and perimeter and I need to derive a rectangle class from it. Right now the program below doesn't work work and it gives me the following error:

```
GS_Inheritance_Program.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual
 __thiscall rectangle::~rectangle(void)" (??1rectangle@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function 
"public: virtual void * __thiscall rectangle::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" 
(??_Grectangle@@UAEPAXI@Z)
```

---

It is due to destructors that I added to the program but when I remove them both it works.
I did some research and found out that it might be due to me not compiling the program .cpp file correctly.  Is that my problem?  If not, what is my problem?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class polygon
{
protected:
    double area;
    double perimeter;

public:
    polygon(){}
    ~polygon();
    double printperimeter();
    double printarea();
};

double polygon::printperimeter()
{
    return perimeter;
}

double polygon::printarea()
{
    return area;
}

class rectangle:public polygon
{
protected:
    double length;
    double width;
public:
    rectangle(double = 1.0, double = 1.0);
    ~rectangle();
    double calcarea();
    double calcperimeter();
};

rectangle::rectangle(double l, double w)
{
    length = l;
    width = w;
}

double rectangle::calcarea()
{
    area = length*width;
    return printarea();
}

double rectangle::calcperimeter()
{
    perimeter = 2*(length+width);
    return printperimeter();
}

void main()
{
    rectangle rect_1 (9.0, 5.0);

    cout<<"The Area of Rect_1 is " <<rect_1.calcarea() <<endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Unless you didn't include all your code, you declare the destructors, but never give them bodies.

Comment: In C++, you must use `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)`; a return type of `void` is not a valid option.

Answer (score 2):

You declared destructors in your classes. But you never defined them. Why would you declare functions and then fail to define them? You declared `polygon::~polygon()` and `rectangle::~rectangle()`. Neither is defined though.

You are basically lying to the compiler. You make a promise by declaring a function, and then you break that promise by failing to define it. Hence the error.

P.S. And that's `int main()`, not `void main()`.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add destructors. You said you added them, but you didn't actually add them. So the linker is looking for them and not finding them.

You could just change:

```
            ~rectangle();
```

to

```
            ~rectangle() { ; }
```

Comment: the semicolon is arbitrary in your second rectangle code, leave it out.

Comment: Also, see Sutter/Alexendrescu's "C++ Coding Standards" Item #50 about virtual destructors: "the rule should be to make base class destructors virtual if and only if they are public". So, your `polygon` should have a `virtual ~polygon() {}` declaration.